# Google Analytics 4 Data API (v1alpha): Is there a way to use segments with runReport?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client, google-analytics-4

We can not find a way to use segments with **runReport** method.

Tried to get reports with segments in Google Analytics, we can get them like below.

[image]

But now, there's no property for them in parameters of the "runReport" method in Google Analytics Data API v1alpha.

ref: [Method: runReport](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1alpha/TopLevel/runReport)

> - entity
> - dimensions[]
> - metrics[]
> - dateRanges[]
> - offset
> - limit
> - metricAggregations[]
> - dimensionFilter

How should we request "runReport" with segments?

Comment: The API is still in Alpha you will need to wait for additional features to be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating segments on the fly (inside the report query) is currently not supported in the Google Analytics Data API. However, you can use the [Google Analytics UI to define an audience which specifies a desired segment criteria](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267572). Once the audience is created, you can use the Google Analytics Data API to query audiences using the [audienceName](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#dimensions:%7E:text=audienceName) dimension.

Thanks,
Ilya

The Google Analytics Team

Comment: Is there support for this yet and/or a roadmap you can share?

Comment: audienceName just returns "All Users" and doesn't return the custom audiences I created from the UI. Is there a way to retrieve them?